# Flow error on intersection type when checking child property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Good morning,

today, I had a problem with using a base flow definition and two types that extend the base definition.

There's an array where each element could either match the `First` or `Second` type definition. When looping this array, I only want to handle elements matching the `First` type definition, so I thought it should be done by checking a property that only exists in the definition of `First` and if this property does not exist, this element should be skipped.

However, I don't get to the point where the check for the property does also tell flow that this property can now be accessed.

I made a small script on flow.org where you can see my problem:
https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagEIEMBnbAXlAG9FQrQA7PAW0wC5QDkAnASxoHMAaRAF8A3IhQZsAMU7s2oUviKgAZOUrVIMtiwrU9oAG55oAV2asO3fuqqCBIsWiygAypgDGsGgBN5uQtiqutREnj46NvpGpuZsXLwCenZCoohhcpjQmIw0yAQsAILs7HioADzSssigAD6uHl7eAHx+ANqRZLQM5gDkAIw9fKCaVTqGxmYs-T2ggrOJ1J10jFMATIOsDeHk4zFrM3PJALqpmdmYuQQAdJCw7ACieO4AFgAUr2c5yCyVcnVuYW8AEoWAZYJxfMQWsEqCBQL9qhxUExIpxIKBXgBCT4XZA3LTIIE7diYZAmdg0YSzMR6OEAxqgJEovRojGY149EZsGbcUA43JAomdElkilUwQ06hwgAqzxkviZqPRWP5eOehAA8vAaAAFdiwLDsNAcrnIHqC4mk8mU6mRdKwLJXOA8D5ZL74qpA0SCL2IIA

After all, it works when I manually type cast the element to suppress the intersection warning from flow, but in my head, this should not be necessary?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I now have found a solution and it's actually very simple: Exact object types.

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagEIEMBnbAXlAG8AfRUG0AOzwFtMAuUA5AJwEs6BzADSIKAXwDciFBmwAxbpw6hSlarQB0G-ESG1QkeRzZlVumgDc80AK6t2XXoJOgRQ0RKlZQAZUwBjWHQAJkrkVLoaalqYOrRE-kFGTroW1rYcPPwxNC7C4pLxipjQmMx0yARsAIKcnHioADxyCsigFN5+AYEAfCEA2k5k9Ey2AOQAjCMCegbIRqApNmzjI87OWeRDzEsATJPsHQkbC6O7qzkAuu5FJZhlBGqQsJwAoni+ABYAFJ-XpbOgTUUbR88UCAEo2GZYNxgsQesZdCAATNQFxUCwnNxIKBPgBCX63ZAPGZgjacTDIKycOhiZySRFgEGdVGcdGY7F4z4jfTNFa8UAEspg0mDcmU6m0kT02hIgAq73kwTRGN0WJx+OKfzU70IAHl4HQAAqcWBYThoLk8jgjYVkilUml0pwFWDFNRwPg-TWE4nNMESET+xBAA

What I have found is, that Flow does not exclude type `Second` from being possible only because there is the property `first` in it. You need to define the object types to be `exact object types` in order to check that it can not be `Second` once there is a `first` property in it.